# If $2^n=3^m$ and both $n,m$ are integers, which one is greater?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponentiation

If $n$ and $m$ are whole numbers.
$$2^n = 3^m$$
Which one is bigger, $n$ or $m$?

I don't know how to approach this question.

Comment: Have you heard of logarithms?

Comment: None of the above. The given conditions imply $n=m=0$.

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen, how did you do that?

Comment: $2^n$ will have $2$ as a prime factor for every $n>0$. $3^m$ will not have $2$ as a prime factor for any $m$. Therefore, $2^n \neq 3^m$ when $n \neq 0$. Similarly, $m$ can only be equal to 0. As it turns out, the solution $m=0,n=0$ works, and thus the only solution for the whole numbers is $m=n$.

Answer (score 3):

$3^m$ is never an even number. Since $2^n=3^m$, that means that $2^n$ is not even. The only way for that to happen would be for $n=0$ and $2^n=1$. Since $2^n=3^m$, we have that $3^m=1$ and $m=0$. This:

The only solution is $n=0$ and $m=0$. Also, neither is bigger.

This all assumes that $n$ and $m$ are whole numbers. Without that, this all goes out the window.